# HTML 5 not applying my CSS

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" id="home">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Me</title>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />  
</head>
<body style>  
    <div class="centered">
        <img alt="Me" id="Me" src="cache/me.jpg" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the style.css

```
.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

#Me { 
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

If I put the contents of the style.css file into a style tag inside the HTML it would apply the stylesheet just fine.  If I delete the `<!doctype html>` then it would render the page just fine.  I've validated the HTML using the W3C validator it passed just fine.

**EDIT:**
I've copied all the files from the site to my local drive and opened index.html in Chrome.  It is rendering fine but it still doesn't explain why deleting the `<!doctype html>` fixes it also.

**EDIT:**
Using firefox's developer tools, there is an error: **The resource from this URL is not text: http://foo.foo/css/reset.css**.  This must be web server configuration issue because according to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files) *"The W3C specification mentions that CSS files should be served with a "text/css" MIME type"* and *"in "strict mode" will follow the specification closely and expect the CSS file to be served with a correct MIME type"*.

**EDIT:**
Run fiddler to debug the HTTP connections.  The CSS files are being sent as "application/octet-stream".  This is the HTTP header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ETag: "3420655293"
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 13:26:57 GMT
Content-Length: 765
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 13:54:49 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.33
```

**EDIT:**
I found out what the problem was.  It was mis-configured web server; the mime-types for CSS was not declared it defaulted to **text/plain** instead of **text/css**.

Comment: ...then you have the wrong path to the stylesheet file.

Comment: try to check your relative path of your css

Comment: What isn't working? Are some of the CSS items not applying or all of them?

Comment: If you have it in a stylesheet, a thing I like to do in firefox is to look at the source of the page and then click the link to the stylesheet. If it is there, you will see it.

Comment: 1st thing I've checked is the path and it's there.  I've checked the HTML using the developer tools in Chrome and the style sheets are listed in the Resources tab.

Comment: Press control + R in your browser.

Comment: @scunliffe: no style is being applied to the page.

Comment: You did not accidentally turn CSS off in your browser? Which I do not really think, as you mentioned that CSS in the head section worked, but not in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Daniel: I've tested it in IE and still the same.

Comment: Create a new file from scratch. I have had a weird encounter like this. Remove `doctype` made it work. Two apparently same files, different results. I was never able to explain it.

Comment: Which server and which headers is it sending?

Comment: @wds: I've updated the question to add what I have found out while running fiddler

Comment: Thanks. You don't need fiddler in most browsers though. Most developer tools will readily display these details.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are your relative path is wrong. If you are using Chrome or Safari, right-click anywhere on the page and select **Inspect**. Find the line that loads your CSS file in the source and click it to see if the CSS file loads correctly.

Alternatively, select the **Network** tab in developer tools and refresh the page. Look for any HTTP requests with type `text/css` that return 404 status code.

Comment: Tried it in Chrome and it's there.  It's one of the listed resources in the developer tools.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to state the obvious,  but did you click the source link to see if the CSS loaded?

Comment: I've tried.  I don't mind anyone of you stating the obvious because I think there must be something terribly tiny error with I'm doing.